# Program terminates after another class is called

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to design a Java Program which offers multiple things like Calculator and tetris game and many more. Both Calculator and Tetris game are written in Swing having GUI, but the main program is CLI. it presents options like press 1 for calculator , press 2 for tetris, etc. but as soon as I press 1 calculator launches in another window and my main program terminates. I want a method that my main program still gives options like press 1 for calculator , press 2 for tetris, etc. even when I close the GUI Calculator or Tetris Window. here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if (input == 1)
    {
        new Calc();
        mainScreen();
    }
else if (input == 2)
    {
        new Tetris();
        mainScreen();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    And So On
```

Comment: *"I am trying to design a Java Program.."* Try asking a question. As an aside, most GUI apps are not 'loop operated' or controlled by conditional logic, but act on events generated in the GUI. It's an important transition to make from CLI to GUI'd apps.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest adding an do{...}while(..); loop around your program so that it repeats the actions and you can add an exit command that quits the program

```
    String input;
    do{
        input = getInput();
        if (input.equals("1")) {
            new Calc();
            mainScreen();
        } else if (input.equals("2")) {
            new Tetris();
            mainScreen();
        }
    }while(!input.equals("exit"));
```

Comment: Doesn't Work. Main CLI Program still Terminates

Comment: how doews your main clie program look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pre-make the tetris game and calculator and do something like

```
        Calc calculator;
Tetris tetrisGame;
    if(input == 1) {

calculator = new Calc();
calculator.mainScreen();

    }
else if(input == 2) {

tetrisGame = new Tetris();
tetrisGame.mainScreen();

}
```

You could also make a constructor where you initialize these variables and then just use them.

Comment: Error: Cannot find symbol - method mainScreen()

Comment: That probably means there is an issue with your main screen method inside of your tetris object. That issue can't be fixed with the code you have shown us.

Comment: Tetris is a whole different class. mainScreen is a part of another program. For example, let's say mainScreen is a part of class A and the Tetris is Class B, now I execute Tetris from class A by using object of the class. Now first the Class A is launched (which is a CLI) and presents a option to press a key to launch Tetris, now if key is pressed, Tetris launches from Class B which is a GUI and the CLI Class A, terminates and no longer accepts further inputs in mainScreen() even if the function is called again after launching Tetris. mainScreen() is just like a menu of options in my code.